# Delete object properties similiar like deleting array elements with splice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

We have object type variable in Jquery:

```
var obj = *{"1234" : "xx", "4321" : "yy", "5555" : "hh", "2321" : "aa" };*
```

Lets say that I want to delete every property from property name "5555" to the end of the object(that means that I want to `delete obj['5555']` and `delete obj['2321']` ).
I am interested in smartest way, trough loop, to do that.

In array I would use `splice(2, arr.length)` but I am confused.

Comment: As per spec there is no way to for see the order of keys, so it may not be a smart idea... though it will act consistently in modern browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the obj to be searched and the value to be found into a function that returns a new object with only those properties up to the value you specified.

```
function returnNewobj(obj, value) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (prop === value) return newObj;
      newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Edit: probably not necessary, but I added the hasOwnProperty line to be on the safe side.

Edit2: It's worth pointing out that new properties are added to objects in alphanumerical order, not to the end of objects like elements are added to arrays. So don't get caught out by that.

Comment: This one is cool, only with suggestion to use if(key in obj) instead of hasOwnProperty.
That way you can avoid case where {key = "undefined"}.
This is not 100% info but its worth of little google research.

Comment: @user178310: Be weary of nesetd objects. If your original object is a nested object (`o = {foo:{bar:123}}`, and you assign `newObj = {foo: o.foo}`), the new object will merely _reference_ the original object ( `newO.foo.bar = 'abc'; alert(o.foo.bar);//alerts abc, not 123`

Comment: If you're confident of your object you don't even need `if (key in obj)`. I only included `hasOwnProperty` because it checks whether the property name is truly a member of the object or was found instead on the prototype chain. `if (key in obj)` doesn't do that afaik.

Comment: As already mentioned, since object properties are not in a particular order, there is no guarantee that the properties are iterated in the order they have been defined. You might even get different results in different browsers! Any approach that uses for...in is not a solid solution.

Comment: @Mihajlo Supic, answerer here. Based on the comments here I've reconsidered my answer and suggest you go with Elias Van Ootegem's suggestion instead. I learned something very important here today.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee as to the order of an object's properties. When pasting your example object in my console, Here's what I saw:

```
> obj = {"1234" : "xx", "4321" : "yy", "5555" : "hh", "2321" : "aa" }
  Object {1234: "xx", 2321: "aa", 4321: "yy", 5555: "hh"}
```

As you can see, chrome ordered the properties in ascending order, like it would an array. Who knows, but maybe IE doesn't do this... Maybe some obscure browser would order the properties in descending order... There's no way of knowing what the actual object will look like, so perhaps have a rethink.
If all your properties are, essentially numeric, there's nothing wrong with using an array, in JS, the `Array` prototype is nothing but an augmented `Object`:

```
obj = [];
obj[1234] = 'xx';
obj[2321] = 'aa';
obj[5555] = 'hh';
```

The numeric indexes are coerced to strings internally anyway (because Array's are objects), so JS isn't going to create endless empty indexes for you, it resolves `obj[200]` just like it would resolve `objectLiteral.undefinedProperty`: scan instance, then prototypechain. If the requested property wasn't found, return undefined.

They're added as you go along, yet here are 2 ways:

```
//Assume simpel object (non-nested)
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\{|,\s*"5{4}"\s*:.+$/,'}'));
```

This, I think, is the easiest way, but not *very* reliable. The most *"tried and tested"* apprach is:

```
var unset = false;
for (var prop in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        unset = unset || !!(prop === '5555');
        if (unset === true)
        {
            delete(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

The last approach creates an array, containing all keys, which you can iterate over, and delete the properties that way. It's here for completeness' sake only: I wouldn't use it, though, simply because it requires a browsers that supports the ES5 spec (not all browsers do, sadly), and there's no real advantage over the code above:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(),//call sort to assure ascending order
toDelete = keys.splice(keys.indexOf('5555'), keys.length).sort();
for(var i=0;i<toDelete.length;i++)
{
    delete obj[toDelete[i]];
}
```

Comment: An object's properties are in alphanumerical order.

Comment: @Andy: [That's not in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) AFAIK, but when it comes to objects in JS, implementations still have a lot of room for their own quirks

Comment: I found that my properties will be always be in good order. Properties are actually ids of folders, and obj is folder path ids. so if i go deeper my id will always be smaller on top because that current folder is child of previous.

Comment: Fair enough, @Elias Van Ootegem. Always happy to learn something.

Comment: @user178310: in  _your_ browser, this might be the case, however... since it's not the official standard behaviour, there's no guarantee that this will always be the case. Check the last snippet in my answer, it calls the `sort` method, to ensure the keys are in ascending order

Comment: +1 because it is the most accurate/complete answer (I'm actually shocked about the quality of the others)

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks... I tried to urge the OP to really rethink his approach... When you do that, on SO, your answer is never going to be very popular

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to get the index of the element from which you want to start deleting elements and then looping throw the object deleting the elements with a higher index.

You might want to create a function to make it more similar to `splice` i you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element you are looking for and set that particular element and any element after that to `null`.

Comment: That doesn't unset anything, the properties still exist, and `null` is a value!

Comment: `null` values can be checked so that kinda solves his problem.

Comment: Yes but `Object.keys` or a simple `for...in` loop would still list the properties. At least set them to undefined, or `delete` them...

Comment: `undefinied` would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

Its very tricky to delete property name however property value can be made null or undefined but removing property is difficult but you can do one thing can copy the required properties in new object its a workaround though here is a sample fiddle i use this often in this kind of situation

```
    objCopyTo[strToPropertyName] = objCopyFrom[strPropertyName];
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/LenmC/2/) is the fiddle

Comment: Deleting a property is not difficult at all! That's what the delete operator is for:delete obj.property.